# Desabilitar todos os Option´s do DropDownList menos o que estiver selecionado

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-select

Como desabilitar todos os `options` de um combo menos o valor selecionado usando JQuery.

Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o HTML presente na imagem:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option disabled value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option disabled value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option selected value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option disabled value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode usar a função [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) com o seletor [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) e reduzir o código pra uma linha.

Exemplo:

```js
$('#opcoes option').not(':selected').prop('disabled', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opcoes">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel" selected>Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: enquanto eu escrevia a minha resposta, você teve a mesma ideia.

Comment: Não conhecia o .not ainda... gostei da simplicidade também +1;

Comment: @TobyMosque No exato momento que cliquei pra enviar sua resposta apareceu :). Deve ter sido uma diferença de uns 3 segundos.

Answer (score 4):

Apesar da resposta do @DiegoZanardo está correta, gostaria de adicionar um exemplo completo.

Neste caso eu utilizei o selector `:not(:selected)` para filtrar os options.

```js
var btTravar = $("#btTravar");
var slMarcas = $("#slMarcas");
btTravar.click(function () {
    var options = slMarcas.children("option:not(:selected)");
    options.prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slMarcas">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input id="btTravar" type="button" value="Travar" >
```

Comment: Muito bom... :) +1

Comment: Bem mais simples que a minha resposta +1.

Comment: Muito interessante, valeu a dica!

Answer (score 1):

Precisa percorrer todos os `options` e então adicionar o `disabled` nos `options` que não estão com `select`:

```js
    $(function() {
        $("#mySelect > option").each(function(i){
            if(!($(this).is(':selected'))){
                $(this).attr('disabled',true);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
        <option  value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option  value="Saab">Saab</option>
        <option  selected value="Opel">Opel</option>
        <option  value="Audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: É sempre bom ter visões variadas para resolver um problema.